# How to Populate JTable Depending On a JCombobox Value?

Tags: java

I want to Display information about customers(client) in Jtable Depending THE NAME SELECTED IN COMBOBOX

Here is my sql requete condition:

```
requete = "select *..... from client where client.nom ='"+comboClient.getSelectedItem()+"'";
```

I think the condition is right But when i start my project and press button NOTHINH HAPPEN

Fill combobox`

```
     try {
            Statement ins= ConnexionDB.con.createStatement();
            ResultSet RS_CL = ins.executeQuery("select * from client");
            comboClient.removeAllItems();
            while (RS_CL.next()) {
                comboClient.addItem( RS_CL.getString(2)+ " - " + RS_CL.getInt(1));
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex.getMessage());
        }

    }

`//Display data at jTable (sql) with vector`                                       void afficherProduit(int j)

     { 
              try {

       {
          requete = "select client.id,produit.titre, commande.dateCommande ,produit.prixUnitaire,lignecommande.qut*produit.prixUnitaire from produit JOIN lignecommande on produit.id=lignecommande.produit_id JOIN commande on lignecommande.commande_numero=commande.numero JOIN client on client.id=commande.client_id where client.nom ='"+comboClient.getSelectedItem()+"'"; 

}


    int Type = ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE;
      int MAJ = ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE;
      ins = ConnexionDB.con.createStatement(Type, MAJ);
      RS_CL = ins.executeQuery(requete);
      }
       catch (Exception Ex) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erreur JDBC" + Ex.getMessage());
     }
         Object tabTitres[] = {"ID", "Produit","Date","Prix Unitaire","PrixU*Qt"};
        Vector  Titres = new Vector ();
        for(int i=0;i<tabTitres.length;i++) Titres.add(tabTitres[i]);

        Vector data =listeProduit();

        DefaultTableModel md = new DefaultTableModel(data, Titres);
        jTable1.setModel(md);
     }
                Vector listeProduit()
     {   ResultSet resultat = FenetreGlobal.fparclient.RS_CL;
         Vector data = new Vector();
         try {
             //Se positionner avant le premier enregistrement
            resultat.beforeFirst();
            float total=0;
            while (resultat.next()) {
                //créer une nouvelle ligne
                Vector ligne = new Vector();
                ligne.add( resultat.getInt(1) );
                ligne.add( resultat.getString(2) );
                ligne.add( resultat.getDate(3) );
                ligne.add( resultat.getFloat(4) );
                ligne.add( resultat.getFloat(5) );`
                data.add(ligne);
```

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVXx6.png)

Comment: Am I missing the code for the button?

Comment: comboClient.getSelectedItem() What data format does this return?

Comment: Try to print out the sql statement and try it out, see if it returns anything. If no, there is a problem with your query. Work your code down. Do not assume it works.

Comment: @ChristianMoen I hide the condition and i try to print out the sql statement, the query work well, i think the problem is in the condition where..